# Finding and replacing XML/SVG element text by id with Python's lxml?

Tags: python, graphics, svg, lxml

I'm new to XML and lxml and would like to use SVG as graphics template and programatically replace some elements (labels in the image).
For this, I have created an SVG file with Inkscape, however, lxml seems not to be able to handle the svg:namespaces used by Inkscape. Saving as plain SVG works:

```
from lxml import etree
ifilename = "ifile.svg"
with open( ifilename, 'r') as infile: 
    tree = etree.parse( infile )
print tree.xpath("//text[@id='findme']/tspan/text()")
```

But I am not sure whether xpath is the right method to find an element at any position in the element tree!? I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: xpath is certainly one way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
print tree.xpath("//n:text[@id='findme']/n:tspan/text()",
                 namespaces={'n': "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"})
```

If it doesn't work, please show us the SVG markup. I'm not sure what you mean by "saving as plain SVG works".

Comment: When "saving as plain SVG" in Inkscape, no namespaces (not sure if this is the right word, e.g. a tag opening with `<svg:sodipodi..`) are used in the SVG elements and lxml does not quit with any exceptions. Thank you for getting me started, I will look forther into the xpath method.